# Adding subtitles to a movie

Tags: windows, video-editing, closed-captions

I am looking for a tool (for Windows), that I can use to add subtitles to a movie. The movie is a movie that I made myself, and obviously the subtitles contains the translation to a different language.

From this tool I expect the following functionality:

- Select start/end/duration of a certain subtitle
- Possibility to export subtitles embedded in the movie and in srt or similar format
- Automated placement of the subtitles

I would prefer a gratis tool, but do not hesitate to answer with paid alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Subtitle Workshop](http://subworkshop.sourceforge.net/) is a great software that I used. I do not check its latest versions though.

It supports any kind of subtitle adjustment, smart line adjusting etc.
It had an integrated video player so you can *add-edit-adjust-check* at the same time on the same window.
Also it supports many subtitles formats, nearly all formats hat are used.

**But** it does not support embedding subs to the movie.

If you think using a second tool for embedding subtitle, I may advice you [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). It have many features. Since you have your own movies, you can re-encode it with any codec you want or place a logo or similar thing that is either visible or blinks fur a duration. It have filters that can be used for different effects and purposes. It have [Subtitler](http://www.virtualdub.org/virtualdub_filters.html) filter for adding subtitles. Since it supports SSA subtitles, you can have many effects in your subs (SSA is a fewly used format that supports text effects on subs)

But as I said, it makes 2 free programs.

Comment: This is a free tool, right?

Comment: Yes. It is free.