# Program to create and "embed" subtitles to a movie

Tags: windows, gratis, video, video-editing, closed-captions

I'm looking for a gratis Windows program that can help me create and "embed" subtitles to a movie.

Unlike [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/713/adding-subtitles-to-a-movie), I'm looking for something that adds the subtitle text to the video frames itself, instead of "embedding" the subtitle in the file along with the audio/video codecs.

I'm also open to using multiple programs, if it's necessary.

Comment: Are you asking for voice recognition, then embed the subtitles? Or do you want to type them in yourself?

Comment: @Mawg I want to type them in.

Comment: Then, please see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/713/adding-subtitles-to-a-movie Should I post that as an answer, or close your question as dupe? NVM, see my alternate answer below  :-)

Comment: I think the term is burning subtitles into the video. mplayer can certainly do it from a subtitle stream in a broadcast mpeg2 dvb stream from UK Freeview transmissions. It's at least 7 years since i did this and i can't remember the command.

Answer (score 2):

Subtitle files are generally external to the video, although some can be burned directly onto the graphic video display.

For external subtitles, take a look at [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/)-

> Subtitle Edit is a free (open source) editor for video subtitles - a
>   subtitle editor :)
>
> With SE you can easily adjust a subtitle if it is out of sync with the
>   video in several different ways. You can also use SE for ***making new***
>   ***subtitles from scratch*** (do use the time-line/waveform/spectrogram) or
>   translating subtitles.

.

> Subtitle Edit can read, write, and convert between more than 200 subtitle formats,

There are so many features that I won't list them here for running out of pixels (won't someone *please* think of the pixels??!!). Check out [the site](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) and be impressed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a very nice tool, but can it render the subtitle text into the video frames themselves (as opposed to bundling the subtitles with the audio/video codecs in the movie container)?

Answer (score 1):

[MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html) can do exactly what you need from [Python](https://www.python.org/) when you first run it it will install FFMPEG for you so needs to be connected to the internet. You will also need [IamgeMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed as per the instructions [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html#other-optional-but-useful-dependencies).

You can generate the subtitles from a file as shown [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videotools.html?highlight=subtitles#module-moviepy.video.tools.subtitles).

All of the software mentioned is Free, Gratis & Open Source.